# cURL requests changed

Tags: c++, curl, http-headers

I've start work with cURL library, before work i compile library. i Send request and have some problem. Code in c++ that i used for work with cURL:

```
CURL *curl=NULL;
CURLcode res;
struct curl_slist *headers=NULL; // init to NULL is important 
 curl_slist_append(headers, "POST /oauth/authorize HTTP/1.1");
 curl_slist_append(headers, "Host: sp-money.yandex.ru");
 curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 curl_slist_append(headers, "charset: UTF-8");
 curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Length: 12345");
curl = curl_easy_init();
if(!curl) 
    return 0;
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "sp-money.yandex.ru");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, "127.0.0.1:8888");
if( curl_easy_perform(curl)!=CURLE_OK)
    return 1;
```

I've used proxy, fiddler2, for check what data sent to server. When i check sent data 
i get result:

```
POST HTTP://sp-money.yandex.ru/ HTTP/1.1
Host: sp-money.yandex.ru
Accept: */*
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 151
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

also i check this data using Wiresharck, result the same.

Do you know why in first line cURL wrote:

```
POST HTTP://sp-money.yandex.ru/ HTTP/1.1
```

I send

```
POST /oauth/authorize HTTP/1.1
```

I've used VS 2010 for work, and also i don't used framework

Answer (score 1):

`POST /oauth/authorize HTTP/1.1` is not a header, it the HTTP Verb (POST) with URL and version.

I suppose you need to put that elsewhere (will look at the docs for second noww)

Answer (score 1):

The `POST` line doesn't belong to headers, it should be set with `CURLOPT_URL`, `CURLOPT_POST`, and something like that for the protocol. Actually, the same goes for the `Host:` header, it is inferred from URL.

Comment: I'm not a libcurl guru, wouldn't say I'm experienced, but I happened to use it a bit :)